# Wrong power modulo (Euler's theorem)

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I have to do a large modulo but my answer is incorrect.
I am given:
$$ 111^{4733} \mod 9467 $$

- 9467 prime
- 111 and 9467 are coprime
- Also note that 4733*2=9466
  So we can Apply Euler's theorem

$$ 111^{4733} = 111^{9466 \cdot \frac{1}{2}} = (111^{9466})^{\frac{1}{2}}=(1)^{\frac{1}{2}}=1 \mod 9467 $$

However, the correct answer is
$$ 111^{4733} \equiv 9466 \mod 9467 $$
What is the approach to solving it?
**EDIT1:** I understand that exponent 1/2 is not allowed and I also do not want to use Legendre symbol, as we have not studied it in the course. Besides, I want to solve it without a calculator. Moreover, I should mention that this is not homework, but this is homework-solutions that were given to us to prepare for the exam. I just try to understand the approach of how to solve this and similar exponents. Hence, the complete solution would be fine.
**EDIT2:** It turned out that a calculator was allowed in this specific exercise. Other than that I will mark the Legendre symbol, as the correct solution for this.

Comment: So how would I compute this?

Comment: The solution to $ x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{9467} $ is $ x \equiv 1, -1$. To proceed along this path, you have to figure out which to eliminate, and why.  $\quad$ One possible approach is to determine if 111 is a square mod 9467? (How does that help?)

Comment: Seems like your usage of $1/2$ power is very inconvenient here. Calvin is right. Check if you are working with quadratic residue with Euler’s criterion.

Comment: It is not clear whether your question is "why am I wrong?" or "why is it 9466?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modulo arithmetic, fractional powers are not well defined. For example, $1^{1/2}$ can just as easily be $1 \pmod{9467}$ or $9466 \pmod{9467}$. In this case, it's best to notice that you are asked to calculate
$$111^{(p-1)/2} \pmod p$$
where $p=9467$. But this is the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{111}{9467}\right)$. To calculate it you can write $111=3\cdot 37$ and then use the law of quadratic reciprocity to work with something more manageable. The only other thing you'll need to use here is the well known fact that
$$\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)= \begin{cases}1 \qquad \text{if }p\equiv \pm 1 \mod 8 \\
-1 \,\,\quad \text{if } p\equiv \pm 3 \mod 8\end{cases}$$

Comment: May I ask why my answer got downvoted? The OP did show some effort plus I didn't present the full solution.

Comment: Oh, I don't know Legendre symbol. Thank you, I will take a look at it. However, I do not think I can use it, as we have not studied it in the course. I do not know why you were downvoted. Probably, I should mention in the question that this is not the homework, but this is homework-solutions that were given to us by a teacher to prepare for the exam, so I just try to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is wrong because of your 1/2 exponent. The operation $x^{1/2}$ doesn't make sense when you are working modulo $p$.

A number may have 2 square roots mod $p$. This is of course also true for, say, the positive real numbers. But over the positive real numbers you can say "choose the *positive* square root" and get a reasonably well behaved function satisfying $(xy)^{1/2} = x^{1/2} y^{1/2}$ and other expected properties. On the other hand, when working mod $p$, the concept of *positive* has no meaning. There is no way to make a consistent choice that will satisfy expected properties.